# Spring 3 jquery ajax delete

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, methods

I am trying to do ajax delete with jquery but getting http error 400.
I was searching and I've seen that there is some problems with delete method in jquery.

Here's my js, controller(spring 3) and request from Chrome.

If you now what is the mistake please tell, or give some links.

```javascript
$.ajax({  
                url: 'additions/cancelUpload',  
                type: 'DELETE',  
                data: {filename : ui.draggable.get(0).file.name},  
                success: function (res) {  
                    alert(res);
                }  
            });
```

execution does not passed here:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "cancelUpload", produces="text/html")
    @ResponseBody
    public String cancelUpload(@RequestParam("filename")String filename, HttpSession session ){ 
... 
}
```

request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/WebStore/additions/cancelUpload
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:uk-UA,uk;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,en;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:17
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=A7DF5CB262C460961BC7B5C7DCB23052
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/WebStore/items?form
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1
1X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Dataview URL encoded
filename:6648.jpg
```

Response Headers

```
Connection:close
Content-Length:1043
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 26 May 2012 10:03:58 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-TraceId:4fc0a8f8-46
X-TraceUrl:/insight/services/traces/4fc0a8f8-46?type=json
```

Comment: It seems you set the content type to text/html and the service requires it to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: But i do send Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded from js.
and produces="text/html" is the response of server.
I tried to change it as you say but it is does not work.

Comment: when i change request to POST everything is working.

Comment: Try changing your request mapping to include the DELETE method @RequestMapping(value = "cancelUpload", produces="text/html" method = RequestMethod.DELETE)

Comment: already did . still Status Code:400 Bad Request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to recive request as DELETE

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "cancelUpload", produces="text/html" method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
```

but do this with

```
$.ajax({  
            url: 'additions/cancelUpload',  
            type: 'POST',  
            data: {filename : ui.draggable.get(0).file.name, _method: 'DELETE'},  
            success: function (res) {  
                alert(res);
            }  
        });
```

you can read about _method: 'DELETE' parameter of post request in http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/

IF SOME BODY NOW HOW TO SEND REALLY DELETE AJAX REQUEST. PLEASE TELL ME

Comment: I found mention about _method parameter in spring documentation
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#rest-method-conversion

Answer (score 1):

I sent a delete request with JavaScript this way:

```
var delete = document.getElementById('#delete');
var url = "url";
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();    
var params = "";
delete.addEventListener('click', function() {
    http.open("DELETE", url, true);     
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            window.location = url;
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
});
```

And the method in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="url", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> delete() {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```