# Delete File from Disk using AJAX and Spring Boot

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to delete a file from the disk ( Local or Server ) using Ajax and Spring boot technologies.

So far i have tried this:

**Ajax/jquery:**

```
            $(".ct-color-specs").on("click",".color-spec-file-delete",function() {
                    var deletedFileName = $(this).parents(".ct-attached-color-spec-files").find("a").text();
                    $.ajax({

                        url : "/Application/removeFile/"+deletedFileName",
                        type: 'DELETE',  
                        success: function (res) {  
                            console.log(data);
                        } 
                    });
                });
```

**Controller:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/removeFile",produces="text/html", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String removeFileHandler(@PathVariable("deletedFileName") String filepath, Model model) {
        String removeFileCheck = "false";
        try{

            System.out.println("Delete filepath from AJX");
            File file = new File(filepath);

            if(file.delete()){
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
                removeFileCheck="true";
            }else{
                System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
            }

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        model.addAttribute("checkList", removeFileCheck);
        return "p/view";
    }
```

Error:

> "Not Found" message : "No message available" path :
>   "/Application/removeFile/File.pdf" status : 404

Comment: you used type POST but given RequestMethod.DELETE

Comment: I was referring to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766195/spring-3-jquery-ajax-delete

Comment: check the ajax call type , request you to change it to type: 'DELETE',

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring 3 jquery ajax delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766195/spring-3-jquery-ajax-delete)

Comment: Need a good solution , that answer did not help me

Comment: there is a mistake here  url : "/Application/removeFile/"+deletedFileName", it should have been  url : "/Application/removeFile/"+deletedFileName,

Comment: also change @RequestMapping(value = "/removeFile") like @RequestMapping(value = "/removeFile/{deletedFileName}")

Comment: I think that the error is in this line: `System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");`, because is after the call of DELETE method.

Comment: Thanks , i resolved it , i will post answer for others

Comment: In which browser are you checking, IE 7 and 8 do not support DELETE and PUT methods

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will be writing answer here , as i have solved with below code.

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/removeFile/{deletedFileName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String removeFileHandler(@PathVariable("deletedFileName") String filepath, Model model) {
       .....
    }
```

**AJAX/jquery:**

```
            $(".ct-color-specs").on("click",".color-spec-file-delete",function() {
                    var deletedFileName = $(this).parents(".ct-attached-color-spec-files").find("a").text().split('/').pop().split('\\').pop();;
                    alert("deletedFileName--->" + deletedFileName);
                     $.ajax({
                        url : "/Application/removeFile/"+deletedFileName,
                        type: 'GET',  
                        success: function (res) {  
                            console.log(data);
                        } 
                    });
                });
```

Comment: RequestMethod.DELETE is appropriate for deleting resourse.

Answer (score 0):

You have written the  @RequestMapping(value = "/removeFile" ...) in wrong format

Path variable in spring is to be used like below

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{userId}/roles/{roleId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getLogin(@PathVariable("userId") String userId,
         @PathVariable("roleId") String roleId){
         System.out.println("User Id : " + userId);
         System.out.println("Role Id : " + roleId);
         return "hello";
     }
```